# What does @get: mean in Room in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

The following Code A is from the project https://github.com/enpassio/Databinding

What does `@get:` mean ?

**Code A**

```
@Dao
interface ToyDao {

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM toys")
    val allToys: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM toys WHERE toyId = :id")
    fun getChosenToy(id: Int): LiveData<ToyEntry>

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` is one of the use-site targets that can be used.

From the docs:

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter,
> there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the
> corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible
> locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode.

To specify how exactly the annotation should be generated, we can use `@get:Query`.

It is not necessary to specify a use-site target. If you don't specify, it would chose `@Target` which is mentioned in `@Query` annotation, which is `@Target(ElementType.METHOD)`

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets